# Деление графа на подграфы с равным весом вершин

Tags: java, c#, c++

Помогите пожалуйста написать программу (с++, джава, с#) или хотя бы псевдокод для решения такой задачи:
Есть небольшой тестовый граф на 7 вершин, на каждой вершине проставлен ее вес (есть матрица смежности и вектор весов вершин). Нужно разделить этот граф на определенное количество частей (например 3) так, чтобы сумма весов вершин в каждом подграфе была примерно одинаковой.
Пыталась написать код, но не могу придумать, как при наборе суммы, которая больше требуемого значения, вернуться назад и попробовать перебрать другой маршрут. Вершины в подграфах должны быть связаны между собой.
Вот имеющиеся данные (матрица 7 на 7):

```
0   1   1   0   0   0   0
1   0   1   1   0   0   1
1   1   0   1   0   0   0
0   1   1   0   1   1   1
0   0   0   1   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   1
0   1   0   1   0   1   0
```

вектор весов вершин = 2,8,10,5,2,6,4
сама подобрала подграфы - вершины 0-2, 1-6, 3-4-5
Не важно, из каких значений получается сумма. То есть в моем случае, например, сумма весов вершин - 37, при делении на три подграфа среднее значение суммы выходит 12 (за отклонение. допустим, берется единица - сумма по подграфам от 11 до 13). Задача довольно абстрактная, меня смутило, что при переборе матрицы смежности первым маршрутом получается 0-1-2, сумма 20 - это не подходит, и нужно вернуться назад. А как именно это реализовать программным кодом я не придумала...

Comment: `Нужно разделить этот граф на определенное количество частей (например 3)` - есть какие то требования к частям или частью может быть любой набор вершин графа?

Comment: Предполагается, что части состоят из связанных вершин?

Comment: Так как это подграф, главное, чтобы эти вершины были связаны между собой.

Comment: *как при наборе суммы, которая больше требуемого значения, вернуться назад в начало* А почему "в начало"??? это же обычные ветви и границы, так что просто один шаг назад...

Comment: Ответы на вопросы в комментариях должны быть добавлены в текст вопроса - не продуманной постановкой вопроса Вы отнимаете время у занятых людей, Теперь как решать Вашу задачу - про кластерный анализ слышали - метод ближайшего соседа? Используйте его аналогию. Изначально у вас каждый подграф состоит из единственной вершины. Затем добавляете в подграф связанную вершину, так что бы не нарушить ограничение на вес, выводя добавленную вершину из рассмотрения. Продолжаете это процесс пока не останется вершин. Такая схема.

Comment: *так, чтобы сумма весов вершин в каждом подграфе была примерно одинаковой* Критерий недостаточно чёткий. Что лучше - 5+5+8 или 4+7+7? есть и более "сложные" случаи...

Comment: добавила в вопрос

Comment: *меня смутило, что при переборе матрицы смежности первым маршрутом получается 0-1-2, сумма 20 - это не подходит, и нужно вернуться назад.* Вы должны отбросить последнюю добавленную вершину (2) и пробовать добавлять другие (в данном случае - 3, получая очередной путь 0-1-3). Получите 15 - опять много, отбрасываете последнюю и добавляете следующую (6). 14 - опять много, отбрасываем её. Все соседи 1 перебраны - отбрасываем её и вместо неё пробуем следующую доступную из 0, т.е. 2... и так далее.

Comment: Да, я понимаю логику решения и под "вернуться назад" имею в виду одну вершину, извините. Но я прошу именно помочь с реализацией этого в виде кода, так как не знаю. как именно отбросить последнюю добавленную и попробовать другие вершины, доступные из рассматриваемой